# Am using the pyautogui module now from Automate the Boring Stuff With Python. My code keeps telling me pyscreeze has no attribute locateOnWindow

Tags: python, pyautogui, pyscreeze

```py
import pyautogui
wh = pyautogui.size()
print(wh)
```

output:

```
locateOnWindow.__doc__ = pyscreeze.locateOnWindow.__doc__
AttributeError: module 'pyscreeze' has no attribute 'locateOnWindow'
```

Please I will be grateful for your Help.

Comment: I would make sure that the versions of the libraries you're using are the same as in the book, since sometimes things get deprecated, but of course a book can't be updated to reflect those changes.

Comment: here is the [docs for pyautogui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) it might be that the method is called `locateOnScreen()`

Comment: Thank you Random Davis & Matiiss , It works.

Answer (score 4):

locatOnWindows method is missing from pyscreeze **init**.py file, you can get the updated code from link below, just copy and past the code to pyscreeze **init**.py file and hopefully this issue will be resolved

[https://github.com/asweigart/pyscreeze/blob/master/pyscreeze/**init**.py#L418](https://github.com/asweigart/pyscreeze/blob/master/pyscreeze/__init__.py#L418)

Comment: Yep, your suggestion resolved the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I *deleted* **pyautogui** and **pyscreeze**, then it worked for me.

To delete First locate where pyautogui is installed.
Use this command to locate pyautogui on your machine:

```
 pip show pyautogui
```

Then copy location.

My location was:

```
c:\users\nitro 5\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages
```

Delete Pyautogui and pyscreeze.

Install pyautogui:

```
pip install pyautogui
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change **init**.py in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\pyscreeze from github:
https://github.com/asweigart/pyscreeze/blob/master/pyscreeze/__init__.py

Answer (score 0):

I have also had the exact same issue. All that I really had to do was to **install the newer version** of the Pyscreeze library. As you can see from this link https://github.com/asweigart/pyscreeze/commit/9edb5d70fbe3b3ee2f2cb710f25401b893d51dfc they've added the locateOnWindow() function in the version of *0.1.27.* As for my part, I'd had the Pyscreeze of *0.1.26* version. After I'd had installed the newer version of the library everything started working just fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it with this method

```
pip install --upgrade pyscreeze
```